# Port forwarding multiple routers for ARK servers

Tags: networking, server, firewall, portforwarding

I am trying to run a dedicated server for an ARK game. I have 3 routers set up in succession between external internet and the computer running the server (or I guess 1 modem 2 routers?). I've read this setup is not quite common/the right thing to do, but we've had the cheap home setup for a long time.

The first, CODA-4582U has port 27015-16 TCP/UCP forwarded to internal 192.168.0.10 (the 2nd router's IP).

The second, TL-R860 has 27015-16 TCP/UCP forwarded to internal 192.168.1.101 (3rd router's IP).

The third, RT-AC66U has 27015-16 TCP/UCP forwarded to internal 192.168.2.243 (computer's IP).

Computers firewall has 27015-16 TCP/UCP set to allow all inbound and outbound connections.

I try to run a port check and the results still end up with a ports blocked. Am I missing something? Should I be doing more? Am I doing it completey wrong? I don't think I need to DMZ any of the routers. I've tried temporarily disabling my firewall bitdefender and it did not help. I know I had this working at some point years ago with the same setup but I cannot remember how I got it to work. Thanks

Comment: why you have 3 routers in your home ?

Comment: @Vidal first router is for wireless only downstairs, second for hardline connections downstairs, third is upstairs for wireless/hardline (downstairs wireless signal does not reach consistently)

Comment: Can I suggest you a different approach for your whole network.

Comment: @Vidal Can I not port forward through?

Comment: You can forward one port to one IP address. You really should have a single router and use bridges (switches and WAPs) to extend the network to various places.

Answer (score 1):

You only need 1 Router, the other devices will be configured as Access points and switches.

Scenario

```
Network 192.168.0.0/24

Router 1 (Primary) connected to ISP
ip: 192.168.0.1
netmask:255.255.255.0
DHCP enable
DHCP Range: 192.168.0.101 - 192.168.0.200

Router 2 (Wireless downstairs)
ip: 192.168.0.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
DHCP disable
Notes:
Connect to Router 1 via LAN interface, do not use WAN interface
Configure wireless parameters as desired SSID, Password, etc.

Router 3 (Hardline connections)
ip: 192.168.0.3
netmask: 255.255.255.0
DHCP disable
Notes:
Connect to Router 1 or router 2 via LAN interface, do not use WAN interface.
Configure wireless as desired
```

What is happening, the router #1 will manage the DHCP and you will only have 1 NAT and 1 network (192.168.0.0/24). Computers can share files, you can use printers etc, all of them will be part of 192.168.0.x. The other routers serve as an entry point to the network(wireless) once they authenticate wireless if needed they will request a IP from the main router. Router 2 and 3 will not perform any NAT, your network will be simpler faster and easier to manage.

If you want to do a port forward you will do it on the Main router, and you can assign a static IP. My Network configuration is as follows.

```
Routers/Access Points: 192.168.0.1 - 192.168.0.10
Servers: 192.168.0.11 - 192.168.0.20
Printers: 192.168.0.21 - 192.168.0.30
IOT: 192.168.0.50 - 192.168.0.80
Rest of devices (DHCP assigned) 192.168.0.101 - 192.168.0.200
```

Depending on the Router that you have they usually manage 32 devices depending on the brand/model. If you are using this configuration for a Small business, please consider a most robust router.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I configured the routers as access points. The computer now sits at 192.168.0.18. Did not make a difference for detecting the open ports

Comment: you configured the computer as a server ?

Comment: all the port fwd is manage at router 1, you should be able to do them there. What issue are you having.